# why this code works well in windows but not in linux?

Tags: pointers, readfile, fgets

i am faced with a problem , i write this code in windows which reads each line of the file. and it works well in windows 7 but not in liunx. i really can't figure it out. anyone can help me?

```
list< list<string> > getTransRecordsFormFile(const char* fileName)
{
    list< list<string> > res;
    FILE* f = fopen(fileName,"r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        cout << "load input file failed!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        char *buffer;
        while(fgets(buffer,MAX_LENTH,f) != NULL) {
            list<string> v = splitStr(buffer, SPLITCHAR);
            res.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return res;
}
```

i and my classmates find it out that the "fgets" in this code is wrong , but i don't know it works well in windows.

Comment: That's clearly not C!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `buffer` is left unitialized. So, it may very well (*and most likely to*) points to some *invalid* memory location. Accessing invalid memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once your program hits UB, absolutely **nothing** is guaranteed.

You need to make `buffer` point to some valid memory location before you can use that in `fgets()`.